# Checking mail subject from Bash or Python

Tags: python, linux, bash, python-2.7, email

I have many `cron` jobs running on various servers, I want to check the status of the jobs via mail using command line. The only way seems to me is to extract the subject or body of the mail the jobs sent. `cron` will send mail regardless of the success or failure.

For example, upon success `cron` will send a mail with subject:

```
Done..succeeded
```

If failed:

```
Not done..Failed
```

The `cron` jobs run at specific times e.g. lets take 10:00, 16:00 and 22:30 everyday.

I have tried `curl` and `urllib2` but could not get desired result. Also note that i can not make any modification to `cron` itself, the only option is to check the gmail.

So how can i check my gmail from `bash` or `python` to extarct the subject so that i get get an idea of the `cron` job?

Comment: At least use [`imaplib`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/imaplib.html). You’ll go through a world of pain trying to use `urllib2`.

Comment: @icktoofay Thanks.. i think i have got what i wanted..could you please put an answer with some info..i am gonna select it as accepted  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`imaplib`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/imaplib.html) to talk to Gmail with the IMAP protocol. This is the same protocol that you would use to have Gmail work with e.g. Thunderbird, so it’s fairly easy to retrieve messages rather than dealing with scraping often-changing HTML.

Answer (score 1):

I had some python  code that used to check gmail for me.  I was going to post it but I tried it out and it no longer works for me. I haven't used it for about a year and Gmail has updated their auth to use oauth2 which is more secure.  You may be able to get imaplib to work as well but you will need to enable less secure apps on your gmail account.  If I have time to tweak it and get it working I will post it.  In the meantime this link looks like a pretty good walk-through of how to get it working. 
https://github.com/google/gmail-oauth2-tools/wiki/OAuth2DotPyRunThrough

Comment: If you got it working please let me know..i would love to upvote you but my score is not supporting that  :(